# How can i create multiple if statments that uses a def function as a condtion without having the def function repeat itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

I'm creating a game where one of the bosses (Suru) acts differently based on what the user inputs. The user input is created in a def() function inside a class (Player) and has to use returns to pass the results to the main def() function (boss_battle). However, whenever i try to use an if code to set conditions for the battle function, the user input repeats itself until the last line of the if statement.

Here is the if code that's causing the problem:

```
if player.attack(boss)== 'mercy':
            kind = True
            break
        #If the player input returns 'mercy' then the battle will stop
        #However the results don't show as the code moves on to repeat itself in the next line

        elif player.attack(boss) in ('heal, no_mercy'):
           pass
         #If the player chooses to heal or fails to give mercy then the battle will continue as normal, however Suru won't be able to attack the player that turn
         #The same happens with this line

        elif player.attack(boss)==('attack'):
            wait = 'no'
        #If the player chooses to fight then the battle will commence as normal, however Suru will no be able to attack throughout the rest of the battle
        #This line prints out the results but the results end up being inaccurate as 'mercy' or 'heal' aren't taken into effect
```

What is supposed to happen is whatever the user inputs (and the code returns) will affect what Suru does: 'heal' and 'no_mercy) causes him to wait (not attacking on that turn), 'mercy' causes the battle to end and 'attack' causes Suru to attack the player back (and continue to do so for the rest of the battle).
However what is does instead is repeat the player input 3 times, only taking the third input into account. This causes the code to be inaccurate as the condition meet by the third input will only work for attack (allowing the Suru to attack the player) and not for mercy or heal / no_mercy.
Keep in mind that even if you enter the correct condtions for the statement, the code will continue to go through each if statement (causing the user input to be requiered 3 times instead of 1).

Below is a sample code to run if needed while explaining the bases of the code and what im trying to achieve.

```
class Character:
#Creates the base for the Player and the enemy setup

    def __init__(self, health, power, speed, core, max_health):

        self.health = health
        self.power = power
        self.speed = speed
        self.core = core

    def attack(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError
    #Allows for the enemy_attack and attack_enemy methods (functions) to be placed into separate classes
    #Allows for the player and enemy to be able to attack each other

class Player(Character):
#Creates Data and stats for the Player

def __init__(self, name, health, power, speed, core, max_health, heal, counter, endure):
    super().__init__(health, power, speed, core, max_health)
    #Creates the base for the stats required for the player
    #Super() allows for the parent class in (charecter class) to be called and used to create stats the child class (Player)

    self.name = name
    self.power = power
    self.speed = speed
    self.core = core
    self.max_health = max_health
    self.heal = heal
    self.counter = counter
    self.endure = endure

def attack(self, other):

    action = input("\nWhat move would you like to make (fight, heal or mercy)? ").lower()
    print()
    sleep(1)
    #Asks the user what to do

    if action in ('fight', 'heal', 'mercy'):

        if action == 'heal':

            print("\nYou try to heal your wounds")
            sleep(1)
            self.health += self.heal

            print("You have {0.health} hp.\n".format(self))
            sleep(1)

            return 'heal'
        #Returns that the user has healed that turn and did not attack, allowing wait to remain as 'yes' - unless the user has attacked before


        elif action == 'mercy':
            chance = (random.randint(1, 10))
            response = random.choice(["You tell the {0.name} that you don't want to fight.".format(other),
                                     "You refuse to fight.", "You remain still to show the {0.name} that you don't wan't to fight.",
                                     "You try to give the {0.name} mercy.".format(other)])
            re_response = random.choice(response)
            print(response)
            sleep(1)


            if chance >= other.mercy_count:
                response_fail = random.choice(["But you were unable to convince the {0.name} not to fight.".format(other),
                                             "But the {0.name} didn't believe you.".format(other),
                                             "Yet the {0.name} still wants to fight.".format(other),
                                             "But it didn't work."])
                print(response_fail)
                sleep(1)
                return 'no_mercy'

            elif chance < other.mercy_count:
                response_pass = random.choice(["You were able to convince the {0.name} not to fight.".format(other),
                                             "The {0.name} decided believe you.".format(other),
                                             "As it turns out, the {0.name} didn't want to fight.".format(other),
                                             "It worked."])
                print(response_pass)
                return 'mercy'
                sleep(1)
                #Mercy is based on a selective chance, if the player is able to spare Suru, then it returns 'mercy', causing the battle to end




        elif action == 'fight':
            print("You attack the {0.name}.".format(other))
            other.health -= int(self.power * random.randint(1,3)) 
            sleep(1)
            #other.health = enemy health
            #uses the Player's power to randomly (within reason) generate the damage taken by the enemy
            #Also allows for a way to bypass the problem of not being able to convert player.power to a numeric figure

            return 'attack'
            #Returns attack - stating that the user has chosen to fight - and allows for the code to inishiate Suru's attack pattern

    else:
        print("you stumble...")
        sleep(1)
        #If the entry isn't valid then the message is diplayed and the sequence is conitnued

class Boss(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, health, power, speed, core, max_health, mercy_count):
        super().__init__(health, power, speed, core, max_health)
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        self.speed = speed
        self.mercy_count = mercy_count
        self.max_health = max_health

    def attack(self, other):

        print("The {0.name} attacks...".format(self))
        sleep(1)
        other.health -= int(self.power * random.randint(1,3)


def boss_battle(player, boss):
#Battle Function

    kind = False
    #variable used for mercy

    wait = 'yes'
    #variable used to determine whether on not Suru is to attack on that turn

    print ("\n{0.name} confronts you!".format(boss))
    sleep(0.5)
    print ("{0.name} has {0.health} hp.".format(boss))
    sleep(1)

    print("\nYour stats are: {0.health} hp {0.power} atk {0.speed} spd\n".format(player))
    sleep(0.75)

    while player.health > 0 and boss.health > 0:
    #Loop runs while both the player and Suru have hp left  

    #The following if code sparks the requested problem
        if player.speed >= boss.speed:
        #If the player's speed is greater than the bosses

            if player.attack(boss)== 'mercy':
                kind = True
                break
            #If the player input returns 'mercy' then the battle will stop
            #However the results don't show as the code moves on to repeat itself in the next line

            elif player.attack(boss) in ('heal'. 'no_mercy'):
                pass
             #If the player chooses to heal then the battle will continue as normal, however Suru won't be able to attack the player that turn
             #The same happens with this line

            elif player.attack(boss)==('attack'):
                wait = 'no'
            #If the player chooses to fight then the battle will commence as normal, however Suru will no be able to attack throughout the rest of the battle
            #This line prints out the results but the results end up being inaccurate as 'mercy' or 'heal' aren't taken into effect

    #End of problem if code

            if boss.health <= 0:
                break
            #If Suru is dead (health lower than 0) then the battle ends

                print ("{0.name} has {0.health} hp.\n".format(boss))
                #Displays a message telling the user the hp stsatus of the enemy
                sleep(0.5)

            if boss.name == 'Suru':
                if wait == 'yes':
                    b_response = random.choice(["Suru is watching you.", "Suru seems hesitant to strike."])
                    print(b_response)
            #Suru skips it's turn


            else:
                boss.attack(player)
                # Suru attacks the player

            if player.health <= 0:
                break
            #If the player is dead (health lower than 0) then the battle ends


            print("You have {0.health} hp.\n".format(boss))
            sleep(1) 
            #Displays the player's health 

    if kind:
        print("\nYou part ways with {0.name}.\n\n".format(boss))
        sleep(1)

    else:
        if player.health > 0:
            print("\nYou killed {0.name}.".format(boss))
            print()
            sleep(1)

        elif boss.health > 0:

            print("\nThe {0.name} has killed you.".format(boss))
            print()



if __name__ == '__main__':
#Allows for the main script to be run and variables to be created and entered



    players = (Player("Hero", 100, 18, 50, 300, 100, 50, 0, 0))
    #Player list allows for the player to have stats that can be changed

    bosses = [Boss("Feng", 100, 15, 70, 50, 100, 8), Boss("Shen", 150, 15, 80, 100, 150, 5),
              Boss("Suru", 200, 20, 20, 200, 200, 3), Boss ("Mlezi", 45, 10, 60, 0, 45, 6)]

    boss_battle(players, bosses[2])
    #Allows for Suru boss battle
```

This is what the code displays:
(Not sure how to display a picture, sorry)

Suru confronts you!
Suru has 200 hp.

Your stats are: 100 hp 18 atk 50 spd

What move would you like to make (fight, heal or mercy)? fight (user input)

You attack the Suru.

What move would you like to make (fight, heal or mercy)? fight

(it repeats due to the second line of the if code even though it's not supposed to)

You attack the Suru.

What move would you like to make (fight, heal or mercy)? heal

(it repeats a third time due to the third line of the if code even though it's not supposed to)

You try to heal your wounds
You have 100 hp.

Suru has 110 hp.

Suru is watching you.
You have 110 hp.

(Finally displays the result but is in accurate as i initially entered 'fight' which causes Suru to attac'; however, i change the final input to 'heal' to show how the code doesn't accept the first input (even though it should) and only accepts the third input (despite the fact the third and second inputs shouldn't exists)

What move would you like to make (fight, heal or mercy)? 
(Repeats for the next turn)

I've already tried researching my question on stackflow, and other sites, using phrases such as 'how to check multiple conditions in if statement' (since i thought a way to anwser my question was to have python check the condtions in one line, limiting the amount of elifs and player.attack()) however this only turned up with ways to make multiple if statments / condtions more visualy appealing). Another search i tried was 'if statement in user defined function' but that didn't give me the results that i needed (or found useful).

I would  really appreciate any feedback, not only on my code (however this is what's mainly addressed) but also any feedback on way i could improve my overall code (not as important).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your indentation in the question is broken and for python that's a big problem. [edit] the question, copy paste the code, then select it all and press Ctrl+K to indent it all at once. Then copy the code from the question back into your own editor and try running it to see if you did it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just asking how to store a value in a variable:

```
attack_result = player.attack(boss)

if attack_result == 'mercy':
    # etc.
elif attack_result in ('heal, no_mercy'):
    # etc.
elif attack_result == 'attack':
    # etc.
```

This way, instead of calling `player.attack(boss)` over and over, we just call it once, and then use the result over and over.

---

While we're at it, as pointed out by David in a comment, `in ('heal, no_mercy')` probably isn't testing what you wanted.

`'heal, no_mercy'` is a single string. So `('heal, no_mercy')` is a single string wrapped in meaningless parentheses. It's very different from `('heal', 'no_mercy')`, which is a pair of strings.

What you've written will do a substring search—which will actually be true for `heal` and `no_mercy`, but also for `mercy` and `al` and any other substring. You probably want to change it to:

```
elif attack_result in ('heal', 'no_mercy'):
```

Comment: Also, I believe that
    ('heal, no_mercy')
should be
    ('heal', 'no_mercy')